# How to select data from SQL JSON when array has an array within?

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I have a table like below:

[image]

And the `Data` field is like this:

```
[
  {
    "MusicGenreId": 0,
    "Dates": [
      "2020-01-03T09:57:48.8476051Z",
      "2020-03-16T09:57:48.8476059Z",
      "2020-04-27T09:57:48.847606Z",
      "2020-02-01T09:57:48.8476061Z"
    ]
  },
  {
    "MusicGenreId": 1,
    "Dates": [
      "2020-01-04T09:57:48.8476065Z",
      "2020-06-11T09:57:48.8476066Z",
      "2020-02-26T09:57:48.8476067Z"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to select `DISTINCT UserId` from this table by **given between dates** like:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT UserId
FROM
    UserProfile
WHERE
    exists
    (
        SELECT value FROM OPENJSON([Data])
        WHERE
            @StartDate <= value 
            AND value <= @EndDate
    )
```

I know this SQL is wrong according to my JSON structure and I've tried many things. I posted this SQL query just to simply explain what I need.

I'd so happy if you could help me out with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to look at [CROSS APPLY OPENJSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/validate-query-and-change-json-data-with-built-in-functions-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#parse-nested-json-collections)

Comment: Thank you! This helped me find my answer which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found my answer thanks to [melkisadek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50179/melkisadek) who posted a clue in the comment section. Here is the final query:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT UserId
FROM
    [Account].[UserProfile]
WHERE
    [DataTypeId] = @DataTypeId
    AND exists
    (
        SELECT TOP 1
            APLD.JobDate
        FROM
            OPENJSON([Data]) d
            CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.value, '$.Dates') 
            WITH(JobDate DATETIME2 '$') APLD 
        WHERE
            APLD.JobDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably it`s logically incorrect way to select UserId by those fields. I would advice You to rethink application logic and flow to find different approach if possible. Or redesign db structure if You need to get user who was probably listening music genres between given dates.

Comment: Thanks, but, I have no problem with the DB structure. What I need is to select ```FROM``` a ```JSON``` object which structured like that. Why would anyone not have a JSON structure like this? Its a quite normal one.

Comment: JSON structure is normal, but as from my experience, you should extract field from DB and convert it to JSON and then work with it. Its not effective to run such queries in DB.

Comment: You **"assumed"** the dates are *when people listened to music*. In fact, that's totally NOT the case. Those dates are the **available dates** for some sort of job applications **of the users**. Thanks anyways... But I hope, next time instead of making design advice based on vegue assumptions, you focus on the question first.